# ldap_search: Invalid DN syntax (binddn)

Tags: centos, windows-server-2012-r2, ldap, iredmail

I am integrating an iRedMail mail server with Active Directory (running on Windows 2012 R2) using [this](http://www.iredmail.org/docs/active.directory.html) (official) guide, but when I try to perform a search in LDAP, I get an error message:

> ldap_bind: Invalid DN syntax (34)
>     additional info: invalid DN

I used this command:

> ldapsearch -x -h win.basecamp.local -D 'vmail' -W -b 'cn=users,dc=basecamp,dc=local'

Comment: What version of CentOS?  Please also provide the output of `ldapsearch -VV`.  At worst, I would have expected `ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)` here.  I can't immediately reproduce that error with only ldapsearch - at least not with the versions I readily have available.

Answer (score 1):

The value passed to `-D` option is invalid. Man page has this explanation for `-D` option:

```
-D binddn
    Use the Distinguished Name binddn to bind to the LDAP directory.
```

You apparently used a username (`vmail`) while you should have used a distinguished name (similar to what you have in `-b` option) for password authentication.

I suspect (but CANNOT be sure) that distinguished name for your `vmail` user might be:

```
'cn=vmail,cn=users,dc=basecamp,dc=local'
```

Answer (score -1):

When I replaced the server domain name with its IP address, it have worked like a charm. So something went wrong with my DNS configuration.